# Merge conflict but the git repository has been deleted

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a merge conflict - Its telling me i need to resolve it in the working tree however when i go on source control on vscode it says that i need to initialise a git repository.

My branch is no longer master or the other branch i was using and is instead:

```
(master|MERGING)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
I would gladly replace the whole master branch with the other branch but i cant seem to move

Structure:

```
Master branch - Says there is no git repo in my source control
Other branch (up to date)
```

Comment: I have no idea what might be wrong with VSCode (I do not use it), but what does `git status` tell you about your repository?

Answer (score 0):

This must have been some random vscode thing. I used git merge --abort then pushed the changes to the repo, merged it on github and then cloned the repo.